# AngularJS + Highcharts - Can't update series data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I'm slightly losing my mind trying to figure out why this won't work, I'm trying to update a series in a highcharts scatter table using data retrieved from a MySQL server.

I can update the name of the series no problem, but for some reason neither .update() nor .setDate() seems to be working when I try and update the data

When I inspect the series using the console, the name is correct but the data simply says Array(0) length: 0;

This is the code being used to generate the graph and update the series.

```
$scope.generateScatterGraph = function()
{   
    $scope.scatter = Highcharts.chart('scatter' , GraphService.scatterGraphTemplate);

    GraphService.getGraphData($scope.component.name)
        .then(function (chartData) {
                $scope.scatter.series[0].update({
                    data: chartData,
                    name: $scope.component.name,
                });
               // $scope.scatter.series[0].setData(chartData);
                console.log(chartData);
                console.log($scope.scatter.series[0]);
    })
}
```

What is shown in the console when inspecting the series:
[image: Empty Array]

And this what's being returned by the server to be plotted on the graph
[image: XY coordinates]

This is my first time trying to use HighCharts so maybe its something incredibly obvious that I'm missing but this is just what I've put together based on their documentation.

Comment: It may be out of scope. Have you tried a `$scope.apply()` to force a refresh?

Comment: I thought that might be the case but nope

Comment: My next guess would be to try to hard code a data array.  Swap `data: chartData` for something like `data: [{x:0, y:0}, {x:1, y:1}, {x:2, y:2}]` to see if it's possibly a format issue on the data input. Outside that I'm sadly not seeing anything extremely obvious. Would definitely assume either data input issue or some async issue on for the renderer. Good luck!

Comment: Angular is not AngularJS. Please read the tag descriptions before you use a tag. The Angular tag contains: _"For the older AngularJS (1.x) web framework, use the AngularJS tag."_

Comment: This article may be helpful: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/194-using-highcharts-with-angular-js/